# Not able to login using Ultimate Membership Pro Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I have issues login using the plugin Ultimate Membership Pro in Wordpress. When i use the login form and the right credentials I would get "Invalid email or password". I tried creating a new user and change the password still get the same error. It was all working fine. Does anyone had any similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. After updating the ultimate member plugin, when the user clicked on the registration button, his information was displayed in the (users) tab of the WordPress admin panel, but the user could not register and pass the form. Because it was receiving an error (Invalid email). Even though his email was completely correct and unique.

I used the solid security plugin. I disabled all its features, but it still displayed an error.

The main problem was that ultimate member did not accept the custom roles that I created with the User Role Editor plugin and used in the registration form.

You must create custom roles in ultimate member->user roles and use them in the registration form.

I mean, ultimate member only accepts custom roles created by ultimate member that have um_ prefix.

ultimate member 2.8.3
Hope this helps you and others.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue....it's because of wordfence security plugin.

You can deactivate this plugin or make some changes in wordfence firewall setting.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rode7.png)